# regexp in xml matches the whole XML

Tags: regex

I have the following xml:

```
<a>
  <y>2</y>
  <x>2</x>
</a>
<a>
  <x>1</x>
  <y>1</y>
</a>
```

I would like to retrieve all the `a` tags that have `<x>1</x>` inside them.

I used `<a>(.+?)<x>1</x>(.+?)</a>` but this also matches my whole XML file.

Comment: Do you have to use regex for XML parsing? [Though your regex seems to be working](https://regex101.com/r/cV7kT0/1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I do (it's in jmeter). When I put the tags in reverse order (I edited my question), the whole XML is matched, instead of only the second `a` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use a negative lookahead (supported in Jmeter regex) based regex to fix this problem:

```
<a>((?:(?!</a>).)+?)<x>1</x>((?:(?!</a>).)+?)</a>
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cV7kT0/2)

Here `((?:(?!</a>).)+?)` is negative lookahead based match where it is matching next character only if it is not followed by `</a>` thus making sure to match 2nd `<a>...</a>` block in given example.